# how to determine if the user click this download popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if there is a way in javascript or jquery to determine if the user click the ok or cancel button? I would like to add code when the time user click the button.

[image]

sorry if I use the name popup download. I don't know the real name for this.

Comment: what is this popup? is that like when something shows up in the download bar on the bottom of chrome and you click it?

Comment: yes. but this is firefox pop download

Comment: No, there is no way to detect a native browser download dialog choice

Comment: I see. thanks for your reply.